# Does beam support the new version of flink which was released due to the log4j vulnerability?

Tags: apache-flink, apache-beam

i am using beam version 2.34 and i see all the flink jar are of 1.13.2
flink released new version 1.13.5

How can i upgrade to that version?
i did not see beam release new version

Answer (score 0):

According to [the beam documentation](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runners/flink/#flink-version-compatibility), beam doesn't distinguish between flink bug releases, so I would expect 1.13.5 to work.